# Regex to match all occurrences of paragraph

Tags: python, regex

Language: `python`

I am trying to match all occurrences of this paragraph and remove them from a file.

I can not work out how to do the regex for it.

Regex, that's not working

```
^#--- Maintenance ---#[\s\S]*[^#--- Maintenance ---#]
```

What the code looks like

```
#--- Maintenance ---#
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /home/fuelvnga/public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
#--- Maintenance ---#

fsadfdsaf
dsaf
dsaf
sdaf
sda
fsa
f

#--- Maintenance ---#
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /home/fuelvnga/public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
#--- Maintenance ---#


sdf safd sad

      #--- Maintenance ---#
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Content"
      AuthUserFile /home/fuelvnga/public_html/.htpasswd
      Require valid-user
      #--- Maintenance ---#
```

I need all instances of the following highlighted, even if it has indentation and other weird things.

***I want to regex on the comments because the content in the middle can change***:

```
#--- Maintenance ---#
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /home/fuelvnga/public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
#--- Maintenance ---#
```

Comment: did u try by trimming at each line? as paragraph meant just extra white spaces in each line.

Comment: even then it doesn't work. I cant get it to select all occurrences of that where the parts in between can be anything.

Comment: Do you want all occurrences of comments or paragraph?

Comment: Same as what the answer below has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
re.sub(r"#--- Maintenance ---#(?:.*?)#--- Maintenance ---#", "",text,0, flags=re.M|re.S)
```

This will replace the match with `""`. Matching is done starting/stopping on your comments `#--- Maintenance ---#` and `#--- Maintenance ---#`, and any character in between in a non-greedy way.

The trick is to give the flag `re.DOTALL` (short: `re.S`) wich will make dots match newlines as well. non-greedy is important to only match between two comments and not spanning all text between start of first comment and end of last comment.

In code I left the multiline flag in, but it is not needed for this regex.

```
import re

text = """
#--- Maintenance ---#
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /home/fuelvnga/public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
#--- Maintenance ---#

fsadfdsaf
dsaf
dsaf
sdaf
sda
fsa
f

#--- Maintenance ---#
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /home/fuelvnga/public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
#--- Maintenance ---#


sdf safd sad

      #--- Maintenance ---#
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Content"
      AuthUserFile /home/fuelvnga/public_html/.htpasswd
      Require valid-user
      #--- Maintenance ---#

"""

matsch = re.sub(r"#--- Maintenance ---#(?:.*?)#--- Maintenance ---#", "",text,0, flags=re.M|re.S)
print (matsch)
```

u use a non greedy matching that should match anything between two Maintenance blocks.

Output:

```
fsadfdsaf
dsaf
dsaf
sdaf
sda
fsa
f




sdf safd sad
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I want, but how did you achieve it?

Comment: try this `/\#.*\#/`

Comment: @robertmylne Explanation statisfactionary?

Comment: @PatrickArtner perfect thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @tejuc In case any more comments are in this will kill text between them as well - and you are matching greedy so ALL text between the first and last `/#` (why `/`?) will be killed. Feel free to post your own answer with an explanation.

Comment: @PatrickArtner hmmm, right. but I have added it to find occurrences of comments.

Comment: @tejuc He wanted to kill all text (including) between two comments. Yours might work if you do the file line by line or use `^` + `$` on it with multiline - does not help here though